# "Image corrupt or truncated" shown in firebug once in a while

Tags: jquery, image, firebug, nivo-slider

I got an image banner in my home page. I use nivo slider to show the image slideshow and it works fine.

However, I notice once in a while, firebug will show the error "Image corrupt or truncated" for either one of the image, eg: banner1.png

But the image slideshow is still shown and works fine. Any idea why is the error appearing??

Thanks...

Comment: You may want to save a copy of the image and load it into various image viewers/editors or an EXIF tool. Sometimes the image may have some corruption (image itself or the metadata) yet lenient viewers/editors like browsers will render them fine regardless. The picky viewers/editors or EXIF tool may then spit out details into the actual error(s).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't mind it. It should be a Firebug or Firefox issue. It often appears in Google Maps page but Google Maps works fine just like your case. If you want to see more detailed info about it, click [here](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4291)

Answer (score -5):

That problem is for the Apache server error reporting in php.ini

Previously, I used 
    E-ALL

That image is not able to be displayed, but if you change it to:

```
e-all & e-notice
```

It will work.

Comment: The question nowhere mentions apache server or php!